# Mysql, slow avg query

Tags: mysql

I have a single table book_log Mysql 5.7

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| book_id    | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type       | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value      | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Book table makes connection with series (One series can have many books)

Create table info :

```
book_log | CREATE TABLE `book_log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_7E42115316A2B381` (`book_id`),
  KEY `IDX_TYPE` (`type`),
  KEY `IDX_ME` (`book_id`,`type`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7E42115316A2B381` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `book` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1158962 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |


book  | CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `series_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dir` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_CBE5A3315278319C` (`series_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CBE5A33182F1BAF4` (`language_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CBE5A3315278319C` FOREIGN KEY (`series_id`) REFERENCES `series` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CBE5A33182F1BAF4` FOREIGN KEY (`language_id`) REFERENCES `language` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=55022 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
```

I make the avg value for a given series

```
select AVG(value)
from book_log
         join book b on book_log.book_id = b.id
where type = 20 and b.series_id = ?;
```

Explain :

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys                | key                  | key_len | ref            | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b        | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IDX_CBE5A3315278319C | IDX_CBE5A3315278319C | 5       | const          |  212 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | book_log | NULL       | ref  | IDX_7E42115316A2B381,IDX_ME  | IDX_7E42115316A2B381 | 5       | bdd.b.id       |   33 |   100.00 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+------------------------------+----------------------+---------+----------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Or

```
select AVG(value)
from book_log
where type = 20 AND book_id IN (
    select id from book where series_id = ?
);
```

Explain :

```
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | partitions | type | possible_keys                        | key                  | key_len | ref               | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | book     | NULL       | ref  | PRIMARY,IDX_CBE5A3315278319C         | IDX_CBE5A3315278319C | 5       | const             |  212 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | book_log | NULL       | ref  | IDX_7E42115316A2B381,IDX_TYPE,IDX_ME | IDX_7E42115316A2B381 | 5       | bdd.book.id       |   33 |     3.72 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------------+------+--------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+-------------------+------+----------+-------------+
```

I have 10 973 results for these query, 42ms for a count(*) but more than 1 sec for the avg query.

I don't understand why is it so long.
Any idea ?

Thx.

Comment: an avg rage has ti be calculated, by checking the hole table. Run an EXPLAIN on your qieires and see what result it yields

Comment: please edit your question to add (as text, not an image) output of `show create table book_log;` and `show create table book;` (show create table is much more helpful than the output of DESC that you show) and `EXPLAIN select rest-of-your-query` for your queries

Comment: What `COUNT` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expect to `COUNT(*)` be as fast or faster than `SUM(somecol)` or `AVG(othercolumn)`. Why? The database server is, by the rules of SQL, to apply any optimization that yields the correct anwer. `COUNT(*)` has some serious optimization to it.

But the aggregate functions that do arithmetic ; they must instead examine every record. So, slower.

You can create a purpose-built index for your query.

It is this:

```
ALTER TABLE book_log
 ADD INDEX type_id_val 
           (type, book_id, val)
```

I chose these columns for the index because your query searches for a particuler `type` in the index. Upon finding the first row of the chosen type, MySQL can range-scan through just the index and not the table. So, faster.  It's called a [*covering index*](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index).

Comment: Thx to you. 
I already have an index on type and book_id but not on type, book_id, val.

After edit my index, the same query takes 56ms instead of more than 1 sec ! 

Perfect !

Comment: Cool! Thanks for giving the result.